# jQuery $.post return incomplete data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've come across a strange behavior of a `$.post` command. 
I have an AJAX request by `$.post(param,returned data)`, which loads pictures onto the page of the visitor.

This is the code, with a little bit of animation:

```
function showPicturesByCat(cat){
$('.local-overlay').fadeIn(200);
$('#picturesByCat').stop().animate({height: '0px' },200);
setTimeout(function(){
    $.post('./ajax/populate.php',{operation:'show-pictures-on-front',cat:cat})
        .done(function(data){
            $('#picturesByCat').html(data);
            setTimeout(function(){
                var inaltime = $('#picturesByCat')[0].scrollHeight+20;
                $('#picturesByCat').stop().animate({height: inaltime+'px' },500);
                $('#picturesByCat').css({opacity: 1});
                $('.local-overlay').delay(500).fadeOut(300);
            },300);
            $('html, body').delay(200).stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $('#picturesByCat').offset().top
            },300);
        });
},200);
}
```

On the PHP side, it's just a loading of pictures with names inside a database, based on the chosen category (cat).
Code works perfectly ... on PC,s, but when it turns to mobile, both Chrome and Firefox do the same wierd thing. 
When I choose a category, the pictures loads but not completely. If you scroll to the bottom, you'll see the thing. If I tap the second time on the same category, the pictures loads completely.

Here's the address

http://adrianmalancaphotography.com/en/fotografie

I can't figure this out, it's too wierd for me. Maybe some of you can spot or already know what it's wrong.

Edited:

this is the dump data, as requested in comments.

```
<hr class="hr-white">
Peisaj
<hr class="hr-white">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Maci 2</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-22.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Maci 2" onClick="showImage(22)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Grau</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-17.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Grau" onClick="showImage(17)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Apa incetosata</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-15.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Apa incetosata" onClick="showImage(15)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Apus intunecat</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-14.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Apus intunecat" onClick="showImage(14)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Nori cenusii</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/preview/AMP-IMG-13.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Nori cenusii" onClick="showImage(13)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>La tara</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-12.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie La tara" onClick="showImage(12)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Ponton</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-10.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Ponton" onClick="showImage(10)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Lebede</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-9.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Lebede" onClick="showImage(9)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Apus pe apa</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-8.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Apus pe apa" onClick="showImage(8)"> </div>
        <div class="card card-block p-0 foto-card my-2">
            <div class="img-over-info"> <span>Camp cu maci</span> <span class="pull-right action-icons"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </span> </div>
            <img src="./images/small/AMP-IMG-4.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="fotografie Camp cu maci" onClick="showImage(4)"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, although I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Can you show a dump from `data` variable?

Comment: I can, but from the computer, where it loads completely. Don't think it would help. You gave me and ideea though, let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not come from $.post. The problem is caused by:

```
var inaltime = $('#picturesByCat')[0].scrollHeight+20;
$('#picturesByCat').stop().animate({height: inaltime+'px' },500);
```

**REASON:**

Since the height is not properly calculated because, when your images start loading, its height is not calculated right, then your #picturesByCat is limited to your wrong calculated value, so it is not fully displayed, but the images are loaded correctly.

The second time you clicked on the category, those images are fully displayed and have right height, then the problem is gone.

**RESOLUTION:**

Set the height back to auto when your animation is finished:

```
$('#picturesByCat').stop().animate({height: inaltime+'px' },500, function(){
    $('#picturesByCat').css('height', 'auto');
});
```

Comment: But why does it work on the computer ? I thought of that, but can't figure out why it's happening only on mobiles. Any ideea why that is ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Maybe you can sugest a full implementation, with the code in the question, please. Besides, it's an AJAX call, how can it use "load" event.
On a second note, var inaltime it's calculated inside .done() event, after the html data get's loaded. 
Like i've said, it's working perfectly on PC.

Comment: Now that, my friend, was a genius move. It's working. Still strange this going on only on mobile, I guess somehow the processing it's a little bit slower than on a computer and the browser just get left behind or something like that. This is going for THE answer :) !

Comment: Congrats bro :D I am pretty sure about the reason. Maybe the hardware or network affects the loading process in 300ms.

Comment: Don't think so, I've tried bigger amounts of time, the same results.